# How to perform the SQL round off?

Tags: sql-server, rounding, numeric

I want to perform the SQL round off on MS-SQL server .for Example 0.5 to 1,1.5 to 2,2.5 to 3.any help  will be appreciated

Comment: see if this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) helps.

Comment: OP didn't provide example for 0.4, 1.4 or 2.4. Too soon to conclude for an answer, jus my FLOOR (2.4) cents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CEILING` function.

```
select val,
ceiling(val) as Rounded
from tbl_name;
```

[Read here about `ceiling` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189818.aspx)

[Fiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fe482/1)

Comment: great. Please mark it as answer if this solved your problem.